# Load C++ from HTML or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, c++, qt, mfc

Is there a way to load a C++ library or class in HTML/Javascript ?

Will QT framework will be useful for this requirement ?

My requirement is to move the Desktop App which is written in MFC/C++ in to Web. How it can be acheived ?

Comment: There's a jQuery plugin for that, but you need CSS as well

Comment: Not natively, but you could write a browser plugin. You'll have to provide a different plugin for each browser, of course.

If you explain more about what you're trying to achieve, people might be able to help you better.

Comment: Migrate from MFC/C++ to Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Emscripten](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/)

> Emscripten is an LLVM-based project that compiles C and C++ into highly-optimizable JavaScript in asm.js format. This lets you run C and C++ on the web at near-native speed, without plugins.

There is list of [porting examples and demos](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki/Porting-Examples-and-Demos).

There are even [QT Demos](http://vps2.etotheipiplusone.com:30176/redmine/projects/emscripten-qt/wiki/Demos).

[Dead Trigger 2](http://beta.unity3d.com/jonas/DT2/) game

> As mentioned above, to run in WebGL, all our code needs to be JavaScript. We use the emscripten compiler toolchain to cross-compile the Unity runtime code (written in C and C++) into asm.js JavaScript. asm.js is a very optimizable subset of JavaScript which allows JavaScript engines to AOT-compile asm.js code into very performant native code.

Comment: Good luck turning MFC code into JavaScript. This is near impossible in itself. Even if you did succeed, how would you go about translating all those Windows API calls into JavaScript?

Comment: @IInspectable I don't suggest to port MFC code - OP mentioned that he is evaluating QT, and I guess that rewriting UI layer is acceptable. In such case Emscripten would help to port core C++ application code to JS.